# Using setTag in listview to store specific item data

Tags: android

I am using the listview with my customized baseAdapter. I was wondering about the correct usage of setTag and getTag.

When I am in the getView function, I am doing convertView.setTag(specificId). So that if someone clicks on an item , I do a getTag and that would be the speicifcID of the clicked item so I can us that ID to do more things. Sort of storing a custom data in that tag for each item

Is this correct way of using setTag? If not then I need a way to identify the clicked item. Position won't be that helpful, otherwise I would need to have a static array containing a mapping between positions and specific ID (which I find it inefficient)

Please correct me if I am wrong
Thank you

Comment: AFAIK You can use the Tag Object as you wish. And no, you're not doing any wrong although you can include this "id" in a Holder tag.

Comment: This is completely fine, but if you could provide the code for your adapter, maybe we can check the implementation better. Please show your `getView()` function.

Comment: @Snake: I don't see any problem storing data in the tag, but better approch would be: implement the BaseAdapter.getItem(position), and then you could implement the ListView.onItemClickListener(..,..,poistion) to use the mAdapter.getItem(position).

Comment: Thank you sherif, Tal. If any of you put it as answer I will accept it. As both are kinda thing I am looking for . First answer gets acceptance ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to use setTag() and getTag(), if you are only concerned with the ListView item click.

using position parameter of the `ListView.setOnItemClickListener` will do.

Since you said:

```
Position won't be that helpful
```

you mean the `position` parameter in getView()? because you click child view of the ListView item(like a Text/Button).

if yes, then this `position` cannot be used to get data of the clicked item, since its the position of the newly created item, but not the clicked item.

That way you are right in using Tags to identify the exact ListView item's child view you clicked.

The other way to solve this would be:

get the parent view position (the Item position in the list) of the child view you clicked, using this:

```
int clickedItemPosition = yourListView.getPositionForView((View) childView.getParent());
```